# java.util.Random - nextGaussian() only gives Z not P(Z)

Tags: math, random, distribution, gaussian

Given an instance of, as titled, 'nextGaussian()'

```
    public static double findGaussProbability(){
            Random rnd = new Random();
             double Z = rnd.nextGaussian();
             return Z;
    } ,
```

I'm fairly certain Table A area values (e.g., 0 < P(Z) < 1) are unattainable in java.util.Random: that is, nextGaussian() gets you  Z's raw value, i.e. -3.4 <= Z <= 3.4, but not Table A area values. How would you get these values? Yes, it is evident that useful values, i.e., Z, X, mu, sigma 
can easily be attained, but how would you get P(Z)? For example, if Z = -1.14 in one run instance:

```
double Z = rnd.nextGaussian();
```

then P(Z) = .1271 or 12.71%, but how do you get it?

Comment: Never, ever, say 'new Random' like this. Each new one starts from the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no class / logic in the standard Java libraries to do this.  However, there are many third-party libraries you can use to compute this.  For example, the [`NormalDistribution`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//javadocs/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html) class from [Apache Commons Math3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//) has a method that should be able to do this (specifically, the `cumulativeProbability` method).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I suspected as much!